# Parameterizing and update query

Tags: c#, sql, .net, parameters

I have a query in Visual Studio that works just fine, but I now need to parameterize the SQL query.  I am unsure how to go about doing that.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ....
    Console.WriteLine("Updating");
    string query = @"UPDATE dbo.IMAGE SET PIXEL_HEIGHT = " + Height +
                       ", PIXEL_WIDTH = " + Width +
                       ", SIZE = " + FileSize + "WHERE IMAGE_NO = " + imageNo;
    //run sql against table
    RunQuery(query);
```

The Height, Width, FileSize, and ImageNo are set earlier up.

Any help, or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

This is the RunQuery part..

```
    public static void RunQuery(string query)
    {
        SqlConnection con = null;

        try
        {
            const string connectionString = "server=KY1-vrt-msqld1; uid=cpdba; pwd=#######; database=CommerceDB";

            con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
            int sqlcode  = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you creating your SqlConnection and SqlCommand objects in RunQuery()?

Comment: Please show also the code for RunQuery. You need fixes in that method also

Comment: The RunqQuery stuff looks like this...

Comment: and thank you to everyone who had replied, working through this now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change your code to use a parameterized query you need to make two changes.

- First, your command text should contain parameter placeholders
- Second the SqlCommand object inside the RunQuery method requires a Parameter collection filled
  with a parameter for any parameter placeholder...

This requires the following changes in the main

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{

    // Build a command text with parameters placeholders (@xxxx)
    string query = @"UPDATE dbo.IMAGE
                    SET PIXEL_HEIGHT = @Height, PIXEL_WIDTH = @Width, 
                        SIZE = @FileSize WHERE IMAGE_NO = @imageNo;";

    // Create a parameter list. Each parameter name should match the parameter 
    // placeholder in the command text and EACH parameter should be defined with
    // the appropriate SqlDbType for the underlying datatable field that will be 
    // updated..
    List<SqlParameter> pList = new List<SqlParameter>();
    pList.Add(new SqlParameter 
    {
       ParameterName = "@Height",
       SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
       Value = Height
    });
    pList.Add(new SqlParameter 
    {
       ParameterName = "@Width",
       SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
       Value = Width
    });
    .... and so on for the other parameter required

    // Now call you RunQuery, but pass also the parameter list
    RunQuery(query, pList);

}

// The method receives the command text and the parameters required to run the query
private static void RunQuery(string cmdText, List<Parameter> pList = null)
{
     using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(....constring....))
     using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, cn))
     {
         cn.Open();
         if(pList != null) cmd.Parameters.AddRange(pList.ToArray());
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
```

In the `RunQuery` method the `pList` variable is an [optional parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx). This means that your existing code that calls RunQuery without passing a `List<SqlParameter>` could still work, while new code could take advantage of the `List<SqlParameter>` to execute a more secure parameterized query (I recommend to make a review of the existing calls to assess the possibility of Sql Injection)

**EDIT**
Looking at your existing code for RunQuery, I also suggest to check about the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). If that code throws, the connection is still open, while this doesn't happen if you use the using statement.

Comment: This works great.  Thank you.  Seeing like this help me so much on understanding how it works as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need your end result to work something like this:

```
string query = @"UPDATE dbo.IMAGE
                  SET PIXEL_HEIGHT = @Height, PIXEL_WIDTH = @Width,SIZE = @Size
                  WHERE IMAGE_NO = @ImageNo";
using (var cn = new SqlConnection("connection string here") )
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
{
    //guessing at the types. Use the exact column types from your database
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Height", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Height;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Width", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Width;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Size", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Size;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ImageNo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = imageNo;

    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

To make this work, you probably need to re-write your existing `RunQuery()` method. The problem with the method right now is that there's no way to pass the parameter data separately from the query string. There are lots of ways you could fix this: you could just add a list or array argument, for example, and iterate over that. However, I've found the following approach to be the most effective:

```
public void RunQuery(string sql, Action<SqlParameterCollection> addParameters)
{
    using (var cn = new SqlConnection("Connection string here") )
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
    {
        if (addParameters != null) addParameters(cmd.Parameters);

        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

And then you'd call it like this:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //...
    Console.WriteLine("Updating");
    RunQuery(@"UPDATE dbo.IMAGE
               SET PIXEL_HEIGHT = @Height, PIXEL_WIDTH = @Width, SIZE = @Size
               WHERE IMAGE_NO = @ImageNo", p =>
             {
                  p.Add("@Height", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Height;
                  p.Add("@Width", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Width;
                  p.Add("@Size", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Size;
                  p.Add("@ImageNo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = imageNo;
             });
}
```

I like this because it keeps the parameter code next to the sql query string, without duplicating the work of creating the parameter collection.

Answer (score 1):

```
string UpdateSQLstring="UPDATE dbo.IMAGE
                                SET PIXEL_HEIGHT =@Height ... "
            SqlClient.SqlParameter  params[2];
            params[0] = new SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Height", SqlDbType.Int);
            params[0].Value =100;
            params[1] = new SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Width",SqlDbType.Int);
            params[1].Value = 200;
            SqlClient.SqlCommand myCMD=New SqlClient.SqlCommand(UpdateSQLstring, connection)
          myCMD.Parameters.Add(params[0]);
          myCMD.Parameters.Add(params[1]);
          myCMD.ExecuteNonQuery
```